# Unix, bad substitution error?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have the following variables :

```
TYP=a1
STAT_a1=statistical
FINAL_VARIABLE=${STAT_${TYP}}
```

But I get an error:

```
-bash: ${STAT_${TYP}} : bad substitution
```

What I want is, that the value of FINAL_VARIABLE be 'statistical'

Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest variable expansions like that. But you can use indirect variable expansion with `${!varname}`:

```
TYP=a1
STAT_a1=statistical
STAT_var=STAT_${TYP}    # This sets STAT_var to "STAT_a1"
FINAL_VARIABLE=${!STAT_var}    # This sets FINAL_VARIABLE to "statistical"
```

BTW, I recommend avoiding all-caps variable names like `TYP` and `FINAL_VARIABLE` -- there are a number of all-caps names with special meanings to the shell and/or other programs, and if you accidentally use one of those weird things can happen.

Answer (score -1):

Use `eval`, wrapping all the stuff you want to defer evaluating in single quotes:

`eval 'FINAL_VARIABLE=${STAT_'${TYP}'}'`

```
$ TYPE=al
$ STAT_a1=statistical
$ eval 'FINAL_VARIABLE=${STAT_'${TYP}'}'
$ echo $FINAL_VARIABLE
statistical
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also do like this

```
root@myagent: tmp$ F=$(echo "${STAT_a1}"_"${TYP}")
root@myagent: tmp$ echo $F
statistical_a1
```